# Proof $|A\setminus B| = |A| - |A\cap B|$ with $A$, $B$ finite sets via induction

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

How to show the following $ |A\setminus B| = |A| - |A\cap B|$ via induction (if possible).

First approach was:

**Induction base case**

> $ \forall B \in \epsilon_0 $ (countable-sets cardinality  0)$ \forall A \in \epsilon : |A\setminus B| = |A| - |A\cap B|$, with  $ B \in \epsilon_0 \implies |B| = 0 \iff B = \emptyset  $. Hence $ |A\setminus \emptyset| = |A| - |A\cap \emptyset| \iff |A| = |A|  $

**Induction step**

> $ \forall B \in \epsilon_{n+1} \forall A \in \epsilon : |A\setminus B| = |A| - |A\cap B|$, with assumption $ \forall B \in \epsilon_{n} \forall A \in \epsilon : |A\setminus B| = |A| - |A\cap B|$

However I cant seem to figure out how to use the assumption in the induction step. Possibly by using $D:=B \setminus \{x\} \in \epsilon_{n}  $. Could some one provide some intuition on this or whether this approach is flawed ?

Comment: $A = (A\setminus B) \dot{\cup} (A\cap B)$, what do you know about the cardinality of disjoint unions (for finite sets)?

Comment: Are you inducting on the size of $A$, the size of $B$, or something else?

Comment: @AlvinL that would be a more direct proof correct? If =(∖)∪(∩) then |A| = |∖| + |∩| from where the initial goal directly follows.

Comment: @Karl inducting over the size of B

Comment: My edit was for a typo (an extra dollar). I think it is eadier to show $|C|+|D|=|C\cup D|$ for finite disjoint $C,D$ by induction on $|C|$. That is, use induction on $|C|$ to prove that if $C$ is finite then $\forall D\,([|D|\in \Bbb N_0\land C\cap D=\emptyset]\implies |C|+|D|=|C\cup D|).$ Then let $C=A\cap B$ and $D=A\setminus B.$

Answer (score 1):

You have a set $D = B \setminus \{x\} \in e_n$. Consider the two cases, $\{x\} \in A$ and $\{x\} \notin A$, and show that the equality holds for each case.

Note that this would require you to look at $\lvert B \rvert = 1$ in your base set, because your induction step requires you to pick an element from the smaller set.